# HotJar Cookies with HttpOnly attribute

Tags: hotjar

The following cookies were found to be vulnerable in a Pentest due to the lack of the HttpOnly attribute.

```
_hjTLDTest, _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress, _hjCookieTest, _hjFirstSeen, _hjIncludedInSessionSample, _hjSessionUser_1324306, _hjSession_1324306
```

I would like to add HttpOnly attribute in HotJar cookies. Is there any way to achieve this?